# Htaccess - multiple rules in one file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

I am trying to do two things with my `.htaccess` file.

1. To redirect to HTTPS (SSL) server
2. To configure my custom error 404 page

This is what I have got thus far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Is it ok to have `RewriteEngine On` in there twice?

Please note that the latter part of the script was obtained from the following article, as I use their webhosting servers:
`https://www.ionos.co.uk/help/hosting/html-and-css/create-your-own-error-pages-linux-webhosting`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok to have `RewriteEngine On` in there twice?

It's "OK", but you don't need it and you are better off only including it once at the top of your file.

If you have multiple `RewriteEngine` directives then the *last* one wins and controls the entire scope/file. eg. If you included `RewriteEngine Off` at the very end of the file then it would disable the rewrite engine for the entire file, despite the preceding `RewriteEngine On` directives.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.[MY URL].co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

That's OK as an HTTP to HTTPS redirect, providing the SSL cert is installed directly on the application server. Bear in mind that server configs vary, and hence might have different requirements with regards to the HTTP to HTTPS redirect (which part explains why there is a variation of directives you see on the internet). And there is also several ways of doing the same thing.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule (.*) /404.html
> ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
> ```

You are "kind of" doing the same thing here with mod_rewrite (`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`) and the `ErrorDocument` directive. You should define your custom error document with the `ErrorDocument` directive, not mod_rewrite.

The mod_rewrite directives internally rewrite the request to `/404.html` after performing a couple of filesystem checks (that the request does not map to a directory or file).

The `ErrorDocument` directive tells Apache to serve that document (via an internal subrequest) when it would otherwise trigger a 404.

The mod_rewrite directives would override the `ErrorDocument`, since they are processed earlier in the request (although this has nothing to do with the order of the directives in the file).

> ```
> RewriteBase /
> ```

This directive is not being used here and can be deleted. The `RewriteBase` directive (part of mod_rewrite) sets the directory-prefix to use for relative path substitutions. You don't currently have any relative path substitutions in your config file.

So, in other words, your file should be written like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The order of these directives does not strictly matter, although it is more *logical* to define your custom error documents near the top of the file.

> Please note that the latter part of the script was obtained from the following article

Well, that article is "wrong". It won't cause an "error", but it could produce undesirable results further down the line. At best, it's simply misleading and "bloated". (For instance... why are they capturing a backreference in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*? Why no `L` flag? And, as mentioned, why are they setting `RewriteBase`? etc.)

Unfortunately, with regards to `.htaccess` (and especially mod_rewrite) there is a lot of missinformation out there!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer - it has helped greatly. Would you be able to advise what to put in the Htaccess file to stop Google/SE's searching a specific directory in the root folder. Please note that pages in this directly have been linked through some pages, but I don't want Search Engines to show these pages in their search results?

Comment: Ordinarily, you wouldn't block a directory using `.htaccess` unless you want to block all access (including users). If you simply want to prevent SE's from crawling that directory then look at using `robots.txt` or use the `robots` meta tag (or `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header) to tell SE not to index those pages.